# searching keywords with dynamic query

Tags: mysql, dynamic

need quick help.
I am creating a dynamic MySQL query for keywords and wants to search only those keyword having more than 3 characters. I have created query but I don't know how to search only for more than three characters?
here is query I wrote

```
$returned_results = array ();
        $where = "";

        $keywords = preg_split('/[\s]+/', $keywords);
        $total_keywords = count($keywords);

        foreach ($keywords as $key=>$keyword)
        {
            $where .= "keywords LIKE '%$keyword%'";
            if ($key != ($total_keywords - 1))
                $where .= " OR ";
        }


    $query = "SELECT title, url FROM pages WHERE $where";
```

Comment: saleem don't only ask question, try to check answer and mark and up-vote  them as correct. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

In the where clause you add the code below

```
and CHAR_LENGTH('keywords') > 3
```

With this clause you get the lines which keyword length it more than 3

Answer (score 0):

You may use [`strlen`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strlen.php) to filter keywords which have length greater than 3 chars.

```
foreach ($keywords as $key=>$keyword){
    if(strlen($keyword) > 3){
            $where .= "keywords LIKE '%$keyword%'";
            if ($key != ($total_keywords - 1))
                $where .= " OR ";
    }
}
```